# React 16.13.1 CSS module class not applying

Tags: css, reactjs, react-css-modules

I have a Person folder with the files:

Person.js

Person.module.css

In the css module file I have the class

```
.Person {
    width: 60%;
    margin: 16px auto;
    border: 1px solid #eee;
    box-shadow: 0 2px 3px #ccc;
    padding: 16px;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Then in the Person.js file I have

```
import React from 'react';
import Radium from 'radium';
import classes from './Person.module.css';

const person = (props) => {
    const style = {
        '@media(min-width: 500px)': {
            width: '450px'
        }
    }

    return (
        <div  className={classes.Person}>
            <p onClick={props.click}>I'm {props.name}! and I am {props.age} years old!</p>
            <p>{props.children}</p>
            <input type="text" onChange={props.changed} value={props.name}/>
        </div>
    )
};

export default Radium(person);
```

Finally in the app component I import the Person component and render it.
My problem is that the css class is not applied, when I inspect the DOM, the Person div doesn't have a class

Not sure what I'm doing wrong

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem was that I created the app using the command

`create-react-app css-module-test --scripts-version 1.1.5`

And the old script version meant the css modules feature was not available